# Wordnet standard database format accross many languages

Tags: wordnet

I am trying to find a standard format for the Wordnet database to use with many languages (starting with English and French). I was only able to find the French version (WOLF) in [VisDic XML format](https://nlp.fi.muni.cz/trac/deb2/wiki/WordNetFormat) and the English one as the original format (non-XML) defined on the [Princeton website](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html)

I found the [Open Multilingual Wordnet](http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) which seems to have most languages in a standard XML format, but they do not contain relationships between terms (e.g. hypernym).

Does the English database exist in the VisDic XML Format?

or

Does the French database exist in the original non-xml format?

or

Is there any other better standard format that I am not aware of?